# Find Index Of Lowest Number In List of Integers and Strings in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I previously had code in Python 2.7 which I could find the index of the lowest number in a list of integers and strings. I previously did this with the example below:

```
list = ["NA",2,3,1]

min_num_position = list.index(min(list))

return min_num_position

>>>3
```

I've upgraded to Python 3 and the same code above throws a type error because I'm mixing strings and integers:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

My question is whether there is a similarly simple way to keep the same functionality in Python 3? I would like to avoid regex or several loops or writing a custom function if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a 'sub-list without the strings, then call `min` on that:

```
min_num = lst.index(min([x for x in lst if not isinstance(x, str)]))
```

Of course, if you need the 'original' index from when the strings were still present, you could maybe replace them with a huge number (if you know the upper bound of the other numbers) so they will never be the 'min' value:

```
min_num = lst.index(min([x if not isinstance(x, str) else 99999 for x in lst]))
```